# C# serial interfacing of Synacess PowerUSB

Tags: serial-port, c#, .net-3.5

i bought a NP-05B powerUSB device and am trying to interface the device in c#. I was able to connect to the device using YAT.
[YAT interface response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSglO.png)

In the c# form i imported a serial device and i am able to connect and send commands to the device. But when the device answers to the command it only returns: *pshow*. The serial read seems to not be able to catch "CR NUL LF" and anything afterward. 
Here is my serialRead implementation

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

            int Count;
            Byte[] Rx_Byte;

            Count = 0;
            Rx_Byte = new Byte[serialPort1.BytesToRead];
            serialPort1.Read(Rx_Byte, 0, Rx_Byte.Length);
            while (Count < Rx_Byte.Length)
            {
                if (Rx_Byte[Count] != 0x00)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("receiving " + Rx_Byte[Count].ToString());
            }
                Count++;
            }


    }
```

and here is the response i get from my console:
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkA7G.png)

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are these documents applicable? [NetBooter Startup Guide](https://www.synaccess-net.com/s/1094_NPStartup_V20.pdf), [NetCommander Startup Guide](https://www.synaccess-net.com/s/1291_NPCStartup_v13.pdf), [Datasheet](https://www.synaccess-net.com/s/3059_NP05B.pdf) For example, try the "help" command or the "/" prefix.

Comment: Yes these are the documents i've used to try and interface. I know they are fine since i was able to interface the device via http requests but i can't find why the serial com isn't properly working... Also I have tried to send "help", "/", "/help" and have gotten the same response as before.

Comment: In that case, it is better to contact [vendor support](https://www.synaccess-net.com/contact-us) with detailed information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a serial sniffer i was able to figure out that i needed to send a return carriage and that C# doesn't send one by default when writing to serial port

thank you.